# Oracle Temp Table

Tags: oracle

I am making the transaction from SQL Server to Oracle.

I used to be able to create a bunch of temp tables that I could use for merges and filters, etc.

I would just add "INTO #TEMP_TABLE" before my FROM statement and it would work out nicely.

Is there any way to do that in Oracle?
I've read some things about creating global temp tables, but I really don't want to do that. I just want to have tables that disappear COMPLETELY (keyword there) when I end my session

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054

Comment: No, there is no reasonable way to do that.  (Keyword: reasonable).  That's just not that Oracle way.  When in Rome, do as the Romans do.  Create a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`.  Or, take advantage of the power of SQL and do all your merging, filtering, etc. in a single statement.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for subquery factoring (aka common table expressions/CTEs, `with` clause...)? Depends if you want them to exist for a single statement, really, rather than for the whole session.

Comment: Thanks Ciccotelli412.  What version of Oracle you are using?  There is some support for private (session-scoped) objects from 18c, including private temp tables, but not earlier versions.